# what should I look for when switching DOCTYPE from html 4.01 transitional to 'html'?

Tags: html, css

According to Firefox, my pages are rendered in 'standards compliance mode' using the following doctype...

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

I'm changing it to `<!DOCTYPE html>` and I see some differences in the rendering of the page. I thought the doctype was mainly for validators as long as the rendering was 'standard' and not 'quirks' but guess I was wrong.

I'm seeing things like a 100px height `<img>` inside an `<a>` was 100px high before, but now it's 105px. If I set such `<img>` via css to `display:block` now it's fine, but why the difference?  again, supposedly the page was already in standards mode, not quirks (if I remove the 4.01 DOCTYPE it really messes things up and Firefox says it's in quirks mode). Or are there several 'standards' modes?  What else should I look for, is there a list somewhere? (I Googled for it and all I found was some deprecated things that don't seem to apply to my differences)

Comment: HTML 4.01 Transitional is part of HTML 4.01, which is the *most recent* HTML specification to reach recommendation status ;)

Comment: The actual particulars of the language don't matter here though, Doctype sniffing is based on heuristics about what bugs authors using different doctypes were depending on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4.01 Transitional with a system identifier triggers [**almost** standards mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Gecko%27s_Almost_Standards_Mode) in Firefox.

> what differs in almost-standards mode is roughly this: inline boxes
>   that have no non-whitespace text as a child and have no border,
>   padding, or margin:
>
> - do not influence the size of the line box (that is, their line-height
>     is ignored)
> - do not get a height (e.g., for their background) larger
>     than that of their descendants, even if their font size is larger (if
>     they have no descendents, they are zero-height positioned at their
>     baseline)

Almost standards mode and the two you mentioned in your question are the only three modes you need to worry about.

Comment: However, HTML5 calls them quirks, limited-quirks and no-quirks modes, because it sees them all as "standardized"

Comment: "almost standards mode"? Well I'll be damned!  and all this time I thought my pages were rendering in standards mode.